# How to read strings from a file and store them as objects without using two loops

Tags: c, string

I apologize if the question is a bit vague, I couldn't figure how to word it. But I'll try my best to explain the question in detail here. I am reading a bunch of integers from a text file. The file goes as follows:

```
n object1
f 12 12 13
f 41 23 63 45
….

n object2
f 45 25 42 425 36
f 78 58 96
….
```

and so on. Every time the line starts with an 'n', I have to read it in as a new object. And every time there's an 'f', the I have to read in the integers as part of that object. How do I go about this?

So far, I've created a struct of the object like this:

```
typedef struct Objects { int values[]; } Object;
```

Then, I am reading in the file like this:

```
FILE *fileStream;
char fileText[100];

fileStream = fopen("file.txt", "r");

int k = 0;

while (fgets(fileText, sizeof fileText, fileStream))
    {
        if (fileText[0] == 'n')
        {
            k++;
        }
        if (fileText[0] == 'f')
        {
                    // I want to create an array of the objects, and store these values in the kth position
         }
```

The problem is, I can't think of a way to split the strings without using a loop, and a loop inside a loop is causing the program to take a while to start. I'm certain there's a better way of doing this. I'm doing this in C by the way, a language I'm new to.

Comment: "a loop inside a loop is causing the program to take a while to start". That shouldn't be the case if coded correctly and is thus not a good reason to avoid using loops. So you need to re-visit the premise of your question - trying to do it without a loop is a needless complication.

Comment: If you have tried it with a loop and it causes problems then show that code and attempt to find out why it might be causing issues rather than jumping to the conclusion that loops should be avoided altogether.

Comment: @kaylum this is for an opengl program, so I'm thinking that's why its happening. If I write a simple c program with nested loops it isn't happening